# AVPlayer SET fps

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, frame-rate, swift5

Hi i've a classic player

```
var player = AVPlayer(url: fileUrl)
player.play()
```

Is possibile to set FPS of player? For example i want to play a slow motion video (240fps) at 30fps

i try

```
player.play()
player.rate = 0.5
```

but this only play a 240fps video at 120fps.

Is possible to change the FPS during video playback

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) {_ in
        player.rate = 0.5
}
```

this works great but cannot set 30FPS like above

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you just want to slow the content, so setting the rate is the correct way (and you can do it also during content playback).

If you want to go from 240 to 30 fps than it means you want to set the rate to 30/240 which means 1/8.

So this should do:

```
player.rate = Float(1)/Float(8)
```

You should also set the playerItem audioPitchAlgorithm to something other than `lowQualityZeroLatency` to allow it to go below 0.5 up to 1/32

[lowQualityZeroLatency](http://This%20algorithm%20is%20suitable%20for%20brief%20fast-forward%20and%20rewind%20effects%20as%20well%20as%20low%20quality%20voice.%20The%20rate%20is%20snapped%20to%20%7B0.5,%200.666667,%200.8,%201.0,%201.25,%201.5,%202.0%7D.)

> This algorithm is suitable for brief fast-forward and rewind effects as well as low quality voice. The rate is snapped to {0.5, 0.666667, 0.8, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0}.

This snipped that I tested correctly went to 1/8th of the speed.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string:"https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_ts/master.m3u8")!)
playerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = .varispeed
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
vc.player = avPlayer

avPlayer.rate = 0.125
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: not work. if you have a 3 second 240fps video with  player.rate = Float(1)/Float(8) you have a 6 second. I think that a 3 seconds 240fps video is equal to 21 seconds at 30 fps video

Comment: @StefanoVet you're right, I forgot one piece of information. I edited the answer with the piece missing.

Comment: Perfect! Really Thanks!